# Ploblem tiling a displacement map

Tags: modifiers, shaders, displacement

So i created this displacement map based on a mesh of windows i made. The map works fine but when i try to tile it there is those separating lines on the z axis. It does that whether i use the displacement modifier of the displacement slot of a shader. [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would be helpful if you posted the map as well :/

Comment: Oh yeah my bad. Here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wO7PG0hdvSbWJRntT2ZiueB8nu0yEIrL/view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the EXR image opened in Blender you can clearly see the lines in the top and bottom of the image, as well as in the viewport:

[image]

Just paint them away with Gimp, for example (which supports float EXR textures nowadays)

Comment: How do you open an EXR file in Blender and visualize it?